# Views rewrite results texfield to uppercase

Tags: views

I need to display text field to Uppercase, using Rewrite Results in Views.
For example from the text value "paper Title" to "PAPER TITLE".

How to transform the text to uppercase in Rewrite Results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to rewrite with inline CSS styling. For example:

```
<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">[my_field]</span>
```

Depending on your design needs you might want use CSS classes instead.

Comment: I tried this but does not change the text to upperase. I can change the text by using simple tags; <em></em>, <strong></strong>. Is there any setting to use <span> tags.

Comment: This idea also works with modification. In the Rewrite Output <div class="changetoupper">[value]</div> then in the theme style.css add .changetoupper {text-transform: uppercase;}

Answer (score 2):

I don't see this question specifically tagged as D7, so if someone is using D8 and sees this question, Twig would be an easy way to accomplish this:

```
{{ my_field|upper }}
```

Comment: In Drupal 8+ this is the cleanest way to achieve this and it works whereas the accepted answer does not. Beware if the field's label is set to "Link label to the referenced entity", as '|lower' will cause the <a> tag to render instead of parsing as a link. So if you want to transform to lower case and retain the link, another method is required.

Answer (score 1):

Thx @Waluyo

Needed to deal with URLs in taxonomy term names for a CSV data export, so this worked great for the output to create lowercase and insert the dashes:

```
<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row->name)); ?>
```

(Value code for my situation was $row->name)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use the views feature "rewrite result", combined with [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

**Note**: this module only has an alfa version as of today, but it's used in over 71K sites anyway.

Comment: I have installed Views PHP. Then I add field Global: PHP. What the codes in "Value Code", "Output Code" and the code in "Rewrite Results (Rewrite the output of this field).

Comment: Oppps sorry. Now I can change the field to Uppercase in Global: PHP. In "Value Code" $row->value, In "Output Code" <?php 
echo strtoupper($row->value); 
?> . Thanks for the suggestion. It works.